# How can I use self join to solve this SQL problem?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the question:

[image: a]

And an example:

[image: b]

This is the query I have:

```
SELECT a1.player_id, a1.event_date AS 'first_login'
FROM Activity a1, Activity a2
WHERE a1.event_date < a2.event_date
AND a1.player_id = a2.player_id;
```

The problem is that I don't get any player who just has one login instance.
[Like player_id 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nddTj.png)

Is there a way to just return a player_id if the player has just one instance of login?

Comment: If you are looking for first_login, why don't you just `group by` and do a `min`??

Comment: Please, stop using the join method in your SQL above. It has not been the standard for well over a decade. You should state your join criteria explicitly rather than relying on the db to interpret them implicitly. `FROM Activity a1, Activity a2' should always be something like `FROM Activity a1` some type of `JOIN Activity a2 ON A1.player_id = a2.player_id`

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the date of the first login of each user.

As a starter: the first solution that comes to mind here is aggregation:

```
select player_id, min(event_date) first_login
from activity
group by player_id
order by player_id
```

If you really need to do this with a self-join, I would recommend an anti-`left join`:

```
select a1.player_id, a1.event_date first_login
from activity a1
left join activity a2 on a2.player_id = a1.player_id and a2.event_date < a1.event_date
where a2.player_id is null
order by a1.player_id
```

The logic of the query is to ensure that there is no other row for the same user with an earliest event date ; the `left join` looks up such rows, then the `where` clause filters them out.